# How are discrepancies with integer division handled in production contracts?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

In my Escrow contract I have an item worth

`0.1 ether` and `1 wei` =  100,000,000,000,000,00**1** wei.

I need to divide this amount in half, and send it to two people.

100,000,000,000,000,00**1** / 2

Each person would be receiving 50,000,000,000,000,000 and ignoring the `1 wei` because of the floor division in Solidity.

```
payable(user_one).transfer(50000000000000000);
payable(user_two).transfer(50000000000000000);
```

How is this issue handled in production? Is it ignored because of the insignificant amount being lost?

Answer (score 2):

in finance, there is no `insignificant amount`. every amount has to be handled somehow.

The primary purpose of an escrow smart contract is to hold funds or assets in a secure and neutral manner until specific conditions are met. But before an escrow contract is created, there has to be an agreement between the parties. and in this agreement, it must be specified what should have been done in case of remainder

Answer (score 0):

The last participant of escrow, who will receive tokens, will get the remainder.

In this case it would be:

```
payable(user_one).transfer(50000000000000000);
payable(user_two).transfer(getRemainingBalance());
```

Rounding errors or "dust amounts" are insignificant for any practical purpose, so it does not matter what happens with them. You could even leave it on the contract itself and it would be irrelevant for the participants or for any accounting purpose.

Comment: 3 divided answers, but I agree with this. The amount seems too insignificant

Answer (score -1):

Given a specific total, it's possible to know the remainder

```
uint256 remainder = totalAmount % 2;
```

In the case where one has remainder (`if remainder > 0`), there are multiple ways to deal with it such as

- **Burn it** - this one is quite common. It consists of sending the excess to a burn address. Binance Coin (BNB) does it every quarter ([read more about it here](https://cointelegraph.com/news/what-is-bnb-auto-burn-and-how-does-it-work)). So, you'd do something like

```
payable(burnAddress).transfer(remainder);
```

- **Give to charity** - create a charity wallet to collect it. So you'd do something like

```
payable(charityAddress).transfer(remainder);
```